# flutter sdk 2.5.3 permission_handler(^8.2.5) status has wrong value

Tags: ios, flutter, permissions

After upgrading flutter version from 2.2 to 2.5.3, permission_handler behaves abnormally.

```dart
PermissionStatus status = await Permission.photos.status;
                      print('## deny: ${status.isDenied}');
                      print('## grant: ${status.isGranted}');
                      print('## limit: ${status.isLimited}');
                      print('## permanently deny: ${status.isPermanentlyDenied}');
                      print('## restrict: ${status.isRestricted}');
                      if (!status.isGranted) {
                        await showDialog(
```

Even though access to all photos is allowed, the result is as follows.

```
flutter: ## deny: true
flutter: ## grant: false
flutter: ## limit: false
flutter: ## permanently deny: false
flutter: ## restrict: false
```

https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

I checked the above documentation but couldn't find a solution.

flutter doctor

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale ko-KR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: After lowering the permission_handler version to 6.1.3, it started working normally!!

Comment: exactly the same here! why permission_handler does not support the new versions of flutter